# Javascript code submits form on the same page in Mozilla

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have this code that I use, to add fields in a form, when button is pressed:

```
$(".add-participant").on("click", function() {
   event.preventDefault()
    $(".participant.hidden").first().removeClass("hidden");
  if(!$(".participant.hidden").length) {
    $(this).hide();
  }
});
```

I added the `event.preventDefault()` because the button to add (unhide) the fields, was submitting the form for some reason. 
This works on Chrome/Edge/IE, but on Mozilla it does not, for some reason. Form tries to submit, instead of the fields getting unhidden. Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: What is the type of submit button? If its type="submit", make it type="button".

Comment: Could it be because the `event` object is undefined? Try making the signature of the handler `function(event) {` instead of `function() {` .

Comment: It is a normal `<button>` tag.
Thanks @Zequ. This is the solution to my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only problem that I find in your code is that your event is undefined. Modify your code slightly to define an event as:

```
$(".add-participant").on("click", function(event) {
   event.preventDefault()
    $(".participant.hidden").first().removeClass("hidden");
  if(!$(".participant.hidden").length) {
    $(this).hide();
  }
});
```

This should solve your problem.